# Blue Cheese has gone bad?

Tags: cheese

On the outside the white part of the cheese has got a bit yellow and the blue mold has turned green in a bit of places.

On the inside, some tiny bits have become greenish too and some slightly brownish. However the white part didn't go yellow.

The best before date is July the 1st. I store it at the right temp.

Has the cheese gone off for some reason? Should I cut off those bits and eat it? I can eat those bits too? It tastes fine now even the weird coloured parts.

Comment: A photo of the piece of cheese would help to determine if it's the cheese itself or something additional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in this Wired video [Gordon Ramsay answer twitter questions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ5PCbtiCpk&t=235s) Blue cheese can't go off.
What it actually can do is turn from blue mold tint to green.

If you search for *Bleu de Gex* you will see that the cheese is in fact yellow and mold is greenish.

The only thing that would point to bad cheese is it's taste. If the cheese taste ok than it's ok.